# Chrome not starting after auto-login

Tags: 16.04, gnome, google-chrome, password

My Ubuntu 16.04 machine is configured to automatically log in. After it automatically logs in, I use TeamViewer to access the machine and try to open Chrome by clicking on the icon on the side bar. The icon flashes for 30 seconds then stops, and Chrome never opens.

This seems to be connected to gnome-keyring-daemon. Immediately after I log in, I see that gnome-keyring-daemon is running:

```
$ ps aux | grep keyring
kyle      1532  0.0  0.0 214384 10956 ?        Sl   14:20   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets
```

And it should open when I click Chrome, but it doesn't. I know this because if I try to load Chrome from the command line I see this error:

```
$ google-chrome
google-chrome
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

If I open a Terminal while using TeamViewer and manually run `killall gnome-keyring-daemon`, then the "Unlock your keyring" window pops up after clicking on Chrome and Chrome opens.

I saw some indication that [dbus-user-session](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1689825) was responsible for this problem, but it is not installed on my system.

I saw another post where someone edited [/etc/pam.d/lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/a/914062/765903) but this didn't fix the problem either.

Is there a real way to fix this, or do I have to `killall gnome-keyring-daemon` every time after startup?

Comment: Does this help https://askubuntu.com/a/823975/689314

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of different things, but in the end my solution is just adding:

```
killall gnome-keyring-daemon
gnome-keyring-daemon --replace
```

To `/etc/rc.local`

Now Chrome asks for a password the first time it opens, as I would expect.